# My code is deleting all rows from my database instead of just one row at a time

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to delete messages from my "messages" table in my db using MVC Codeigniter framework for  a social networking site that I am creating for college. I have 4 fields in my "messages" table in my db - id, to, from and message. I'm hitting a snag - the code is deleting all rows from the "messages" table. I just want to delete one row (message) at a time.  Although all messages are deleted – it throws an error: Message: Undefined variable: username - should I be passing “username” through? -  any help would be much appreciated.

```
This is the function in my Controller:

function delMessage($username) {
    $this->load->model('messages');
    $data['messages'] = $this->messages->deleteUserMessage($username);
    $this->load->view('message', $data);
}

This is the function in my Model:

function deleteUserMessage($username) {
    $this->db->where('from', $username);
    $this->db->or_where('to', $username); 
    $query = $this->db->get('messages');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
        $messages = $query->result_array();
        $this->db->where('from', $username);
        $this->db->or_where('to', $username); 
        $this->db->delete('messages');
        return $messages;
    }
}

This is the code in my view:

  <?php foreach($messages as $message): ?>

          <li><?=$message['from']?> says...: "<?=$message['message']?>"<br/><?=anchor("message/delMessage/$username", 'Delete Message')?></li>      
         <?php endforeach?>
```

Comment: @Mark Baker:  I see you fixed the typo in the OP's posted code.  How are we sure this was just a typo on SO and not really in his code?

Comment: That was almost certainly just a typo on SO. The code wouldn't have executed at all if that was in his actual PHP file.

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo when copying here. I have loaded ('messages')

Comment: What is the value of `$username`?

Comment: @Sparky - if that had been in the original code, it would have thrown a parse error, not executed the code

Comment: Hi Yan, $username holds the value of the user that is that is logged in. Well, it does in other parts of the application! This one is confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

Your Model should be like this,

```
function deleteUserMessage($username) {
    $this->db->where('from', $username);
    $this->db->or_where('to', $username); 
    $query = $this->db->delete('messages');
    if($query) {
        return true;
    }
}
```